Why does sunflower oil turned to green after frying?
After frying foods, for example, chicken or cutlets(mix of meat and potato) with frying sunflower oil, the oil turns green/greenish, is this oil spoiled and bad?
Shouldn't I use the rest of the oil bottle? (I mean oil that has not been used yet.)
The following photos are of when the oil is cooled.
Thank you




Is this can be related to my problem?

Source:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10048579/

Welcome to SA!  The oil doesn't look green to me in the photo.  Is it greener than that in person?

@FuzzyChef Thank you, No, the oil looks the same.

That oil just looks dirty to me.  I wouldn't re-use it, but I don't see any visual indication that there's anything wrong with it.
It is normal for oil to turn dark with use, and darkening is a sign that the oil is no longer reusable and should be thrown away or recycled.

Sunflower oil in particular is known to turn green in the presence of bases, apparently

@fyrepenguin that sounds like an answer!  Why don't you post it as one?

I figured it could be relevant, in that sunflower oil can turn green in some situations, but it’s not clear to me that it’s the case here. But I had vaguely recalled seeing someone mention their sunflower oil cookies turning green after baking them

@fyrepenguin and  FuzzyChef
I edited my question and added details.
Please see:
Is this can be related to my problem?
